# Remove multiple periods from character string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I have some similar column names for example:

```
Eagles.....Brown.Bears.......
Western.Bulls......Great.Lions....
```

I would like to extract the words. For example from the first:

```
'Eagles' and 'Brown.Bears'
```

for the second:

```
'Western.Bulls' and 'Great.Lions'
```

There are always periods between team names (>2 periods but vary in number '....') and there is always one period in place of a space within a team name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, "\\w+(\\.\\w+)?")
#[[1]]
#[1] "Eagles"      "Brown.Bears"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Western.Bulls" "Great.Lions"
```

Or using `strsplit` from `base R`

```
strsplit(str1, "\\.{2,}")
#[[1]]
#[1] "Eagles"      "Brown.Bears"

#[[2]]
#[1] "Western.Bulls" "Great.Lions"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Eagles.....Brown.Bears.......", "Western.Bulls......Great.Lions....")
```